# Drag a file from website and upload into webiste file uploader instead from deskop

Tags: javascript, file, upload

I do not know that much about JavaScript. Since there is a way to drag a file from desktop to the website file uploader. Now, let's suppose both image and drag drop file uploader are on the same page. Can we drag that image and upload into the file uploader?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused to what it is you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it.  Can you please provide some more context?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the website has the option to upload a file by the drag and drop option which we usually drag and drop from our desktop .
But instead of dragging it from our desktop can we drag the image from the same website ? 
Just think that the image is also in the page from where we can upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

- if you wants to make this image able to be dragged you can set `draggable` to true

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
img.draggable = true;
```

- now you can drag this image anywhere in the page

Comment: The image file also needs to get uploaded into the file upload system as shown in an above image.